# Trouble setting up Local Node on Tails

Tags: monerod, full-node, tor

I'm trying to run the commands to download the blockchain to an external drive in Tails. I tried to put a folder for the blockchain on an ext4 partition but it won't let me write to it so I thought I could just use my NTFS partition. Any reason not to do that?

This is what I put into the command line and what I got. What am I doing wrong?

```
amnesia@amnesia:~$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -m tcp --dport 18081 -j ACCEPT

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for amnesia: 
amnesia@amnesia:~$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -m tcp --dport 18081 -j ACCEPT
[sudo] password for amnesia: 
amnesia@amnesia:~$ DNS_PUBLIC=tcp torsocks ./monerod --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --no-igd --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 \
>     --data-dir '/media/amnesia/My Passport/Blockchain' 
ERROR: ./monerod cannot be found.
amnesia@amnesia:~$
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the terminal in the same directory as `monerod`? You can use `ls -a` to check.

Comment: I don't think it was. I clicked on the monero folder and opened int terminal. Now it is working but it keeps telling me `1561315484 ERROR torsocks[17127]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:533)
[1561315484] libunbound[17127:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 77.109.148.137`

Comment: Can you type `status` in `monerod` and post the output here?

Comment: I typed `status` in the current terminal I have running and got this: `Height: 54401/1863433 (2.9%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 2.32 MH/s, v1, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 1h 17m 1s`

Comment: That looks OK. A blockchain sync from scratch on Tails may take quite some time to complete though. Thus, please take that into account.

Comment: is it normal to get this warning: `2019-06-24 00:38:25.053 [P2P2] WARN  global src/p2p/net_node.inl:1338 No incoming connections - check firewalls/routers allow port 18080`     ?

Comment: Its stopped giving me updates on the sync and now its just shwoing a list of commands. It repeated the list of commands many times.

Comment: That warning is normal and does not inhibit the daemon from syncing properly.

Comment: Do you mean the `status` command does not give a proper output anymore?

Comment: I put this project down for a bit. Now I'm getting lots of these errors ```1562423540 ERROR torsocks[20315]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:533)
[1562423540] libunbound[20315:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 77.109.148.137
1562423557 ERROR torsocks[20315]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:533)
[1562423557] libunbound[20315:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 77.109.148.137```     could it be because my version says 0.14.0.0 instead of 0.14.0.2?

Comment: Can you perhaps try with v0.14.1.0? Also, does the `status` command return anything?

Comment: No the status command didn't do anything. It wasn't synchronizing. Now when I extract the new version do I just delete the old folder and package?

Comment: Correct. Let me know if the new version works.

Comment: I made a good bit of progress last night. However now after stopping it and trying to restart it with a wired connection I'm getting this message     ```2019-07-09 03:52:04.823 W The blockchain is on a rotating drive: this will be very slow, use an SSD if possible
2019-07-09 03:52:04.862 W LMDB memory map needs to be resized, doing that now.
2019-07-09 03:52:04.862 I LMDB Mapsize increased.  Old: 7329MiB, New: 8353MiB
Segmentation fault```   and then it just stops

Comment: Did you incur an unexpected shutdown (i.e. power outage or system crash)? Or did you shut down the daemon (monerod) ungracefully?

Comment: I think I just exited the terminal window when I stopped it.

Comment: `Segmentation fault` alas usually means that the blockchain file is corrupted. Do you have a backup? Also, you are using v0.14.1.0 right?